# Total comment count between threads with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to come up with a query that will return a list of threads between two users and the total number of comments in that thread - through multiple joins.

Looking at [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fe01cf8/1) I'm not getting the results I'm expecting. I want to return a list of suppliers that submitted a response to a request on an order (the threads) and the total number of comments in that thread.  If there are no comments between a supplier and a buyer it should return 0 for the comments.

Expected Result:

```
order_id | supplier_id | buyer_id | comment_count
---------+-------------+----------+---------------
1        | 1           | 2        | 4
2        | 3           | 4        | 5
2        | 5           | 2        | 0
```

Actual Result:

```
order_id | supplier_id | buyer_id | comment_count
---------+-------------+----------+--------------
1        | 1           | 2        | 4
1        | 3           | 2        | 4
2        | 1           | 4        | 5
2        | 3           | 4        | 5
2        | 5           | 2        | 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.